# Inline Notation for the Diagonal of a Matrix?

Tags: symbols, matrices

Is there a `LaTeX` command to indicate one is referring to the elements of a matrix diagonal?  Something like `\diag{X}`?  It seems like this must exist but I cannot find it (search terms too common in multiple contexts).

Note: I don't want to display the matrix in any way, just refer to the diagonal.

Comment: How about `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\diag}{diag}
\begin{document}
$A=\diag(a_1,\dots,a_n)$
\end{document}`?

Comment: This would work, thank you.  Since you answered this way I guess there is not a built-in version in some package (?)

Comment: I do not know if there is a package but it does not seem to be part of `amsmath` nor `mathtools`. It is not unusual that one has to define some math operators oneself but of course there could be a not too harmful package that does that for you.

Comment: +1 "not too harmful package" great phrase.  Glad to accept if you want to  move your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One thing that one always can do is to define the math operators one needs using `\DeclareMathOperator`. For example, for `\diag` one could use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\diag}{diag}
\begin{document}
$A=\diag(a_1,\dots,a_n)$
\end{document}
```

P.S. I personally would hesitate to load a package just in order to avoid defining one operator. In particular, I do not recommend the `physics` package (yet this one does not seem to define `\diag` anyway).